WSO2 Login denied
" User
Erreur d'authentification !
Quelque chose s'est mal passé pendant le processus d'authentification. Veuillez essayer de vous connecter à nouveau"
why I obtain this message when Itry to login with my account. But with admin credentiels it's ok
I can't Login to my account wso2

Can you share the API Manager version and which portal you are trying to login? Is it the Publisher, Developer Portal, or the Admin Portal? Furthermore, are you seeing any errors in the wso2carbon logs during the login?
